# What is the best way to position a title, or even link, in the middle of this web page?

Tags: html, css

**strong text**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8em;
  left: 8em;
  font-family: 'Serif';
  font-size: 7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: auto;
  line-height: .8em;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: .2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
**Below is the Home Page button I am trying to create**
**I know that is just a Header tag and not a button. I know how to make a button but my main problem is positioning**

**Nomatter what I do, the positioning is always at the very top of the page. My goal is to get it smack dab in the middle, over the graphic animations.**

  <h1> Enter Home Page</h1>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
    camera.position.z = 5;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    })

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0xF7F7F7
    });
    //var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    //scene.add(mesh);

    meshX = -10;
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
      mesh.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
      mesh.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
      scene.add(mesh);
      meshX += 1;
    }


    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 1000)
    light.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 2, 1000)
    light.position.set(0, 0, 25);
    scene.add(light);

    var render = function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);


      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

      var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
      for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        this.tl = new TimelineMax();
        this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, 1, {
          x: 2,
          ease: Expo.easeOut
        })
        this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, .5, {
          x: .5,
          ease: Expo.easeOut
        })
        this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.position, .5, {
          x: 2,
          ease: Expo.easeOut
        })
        this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.rotation, .5, {
          y: Math.PI * .5,
          ease: Expo.easeOut
        }, "=-1.5")
      }
    }



    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    render();
  </script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried adding this in, but all it does it put the button at the very top of the page.

<style>
.container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.vertical-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical-center">
    <button>Centered Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to better understand how a good question is built. I don't know if my answer is correct, but the formatting of a question is important to get a good answer.

Anyway, I hope this is what you were looking for. I created a `fixed` container which fill the whole viewport and with `display: flex` I centered the content with `align-items` and `justify-content`.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
camera.position.z = 5;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xF7F7F7
});
//var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

//scene.add(mesh);

meshX = -10;
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  mesh.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  mesh.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  scene.add(mesh);
  meshX += 1;
}


var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 1000)
light.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(light);

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 2, 1000)
light.position.set(0, 0, 25);
scene.add(light);

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);


  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
  for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
    this.tl = new TimelineMax();
    this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, 1, {
      x: 2,
      ease: Expo.easeOut
    })
    this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, .5, {
      x: .5,
      ease: Expo.easeOut
    })
    this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.position, .5, {
      x: 2,
      ease: Expo.easeOut
    })
    this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.rotation, .5, {
      y: Math.PI * .5,
      ease: Expo.easeOut
    }, "=-1.5")
  }
}



window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
render();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}

.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.center h1 {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  line-height: .8em;
  font-family: 'Serif';
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: .2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="center">
  <h1> Enter Home Page</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Baro I ran your edits and it looks perfect. Laying on top of the graphics like that is exactly what I was searching for. How would you suggest I better phrase my questions? I'm still a noob on stack overflow. I also write my javascript inside my html files. The only thing I seperate is my css because it is so lengthy.